# help aligning with 960 gs

Tags: html, css, 960.gs

here is some code:

```
<div id="featured" class="grid_8">
<img src="images/rotating.jpg" />
</div> <!-- end featured -->

<div id="upcoming" class="grid_4">
<h2>Upcoming Event Dates</h2>
</div>

<div id="clear"></div>
```

yet the id "upcoming", dips down a bit. the text should line up with the top of that image.

[image]

adding alpha to grid_8 and omega to grid_4 doesn't work.
how can i fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

H2 by default has a margin on the top. Try removing this.

Answer (score 0):

Without an actual page to look at or your CSS, I'd say it's probably padding on #upcoming or a combination of padding and/or margin on the H2 element.

Comment: i was typing in "the 960 reset file removes the padding on the h2". then i added a margin:0; and boom it's gone. thanks guys